# Failed to create Context 0x3005 emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to create an emulator to test my application,but I am getting the following error and my Emulator is just showing Black screen.

```
 Starting emulator for AVD 'AVD_for_Xperia_Z1_by_Sony'
Failed to create Context 0x3005
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
could not get wglGetExtensionsStringARB
```

I google a lot to solve this issue,but none of them solved my issue.

Can anyone suggest me how to solve this issue and what exactly this error mean.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Google this error, I found some ways to fix: (from code.google.com, stackoverflow.com, ...)

- Increase RAM for emulator
- Move DLL (4 files DLL name start with "lib") from directory "sdk\tools\lib" to "sdk\tools"
- Add SDK directory to PATH environment
- Run emulator-arm.exe instead of emulator.exe

But all not work for me!

Finally, i found other solution: update graphics driver
I update intel graphics drivers: http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect/graphics (access via Internet Exporer)
And it works for me. Now i can run android emulator without error,

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enable "Use host GPU" in emulator settings. Without normal GPU you can't run OpenGLES apps.

Comment: May be your GPU is not supported. You can try http://www.genymotion.com/ for testing OpenGLES apps. It has better GPU emulation, than Android Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the following files from  \tools\lib to the tools folder:

libEGL_translator.dll

libGLES_CM_translator.dll

libGLES_V2_translator.dll

libOpenglRender.dll

and the problem solved.